# UITableView data to HTML email body using NSMutableDictionary

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to figure out the best way to display the contents of `UITableView` data into the HTML email body.

Each table cell has a date and description, these are in a custom `UITableViewCell` class.

The problem is that I am using a ton of date calculations based on core data to display the results in the `UITableView`, which means I'd have to copy all that over to create the data for the HTML data because I'm not simply dumping core data to the table, but rather displaying the calculated dates.

My options as far as I can tell are:

1. As I do the calculation for each date in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I could add the result to an `NSMutableDictionary` and then loop through that to create the HTML data.
2. Figure out some way to loop through the cell data in the table.  I would like to try to go this route because it may become necessary at some point to allow the user to "override" the calculated date manually, so I would want that to be the date that gets exported to HTML.

Here is the email code, if it will help in understanding what I'm trying to do.  I was playing around with trying to pull the items from an array, with no success.

```
// name of array is results


if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mailer setSubject:subject];

    NSString *emailTop = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><table border=1><tr><th>Date</th><th>Event</th></tr>"];


    for(int i=0;i<[self.results count];i++){

        NSString *expDate = [self.results objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *expDesc = [self.results objectAtIndex:i]];

        emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<tr><td>%@</td><td>%@</td><tr>",expDate,expDesc];

    }

    NSString *emailBottom = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"</table></body></html>"];
    NSString *emailComplete = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",emailTop,emailBody,emailBottom];


    [mailer setMessageBody:emailComplete isHTML:YES];
    [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

As requested...note that the results array is the original core data pull, not to be confused with the array I was trying to create for each cell data

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellResults";

// Configure the cell...

ResultsCell *resultscell = (ResultsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
NSManagedObject *result = [self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

//  populate the cells
[resultscell.labelEventDesc setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result valueForKey:@"eventdesc"]]];
[resultscell.labelWeeksOut setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@ weeks",[result valueForKey:@"weeksout"]]];


//  calculate the event dates
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

NSString *weeks = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",[result valueForKey:@"weeksout"]];
int intWeeks = [weeks intValue];

[offsetComponents setWeek:intWeeks];

NSString *wkday = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result valueForKey:@"dow"]];
int targetWeekday = [wkday intValue];


NSDate *eventDt= [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:[self trialDate] options:0];
NSDateFormatter* dateF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateF setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"];
[dateF setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

if (targetWeekday==0) {

    //  if there is no preference for a specific day of week
    NSString *eventDtforDisplay = [dateF stringFromDate:eventDt];
    resultscell.labelEventDesc.numberOfLines=0;
    [resultscell.labelEventDesc sizeToFit];
    [resultscell.textEventDate setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",eventDtforDisplay]];


} else {

    //if there is a day of week preference
    NSDateComponents *fComp = [gregorian components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:eventDt];
    NSInteger weekday = fComp.weekday;

    NSDateComponents *c = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];

    c.day = targetWeekday - weekday;

    NSDate *resultDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:c toDate:eventDt options:0];
    NSDateFormatter* newDateF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [newDateF setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"];
    [newDateF setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    NSString *eventDtforDisplay = [newDateF stringFromDate:resultDate];
    resultscell.labelEventDesc.numberOfLines=0;
    [resultscell.labelEventDesc sizeToFit];
    [resultscell.textEventDate setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",eventDtforDisplay]];
}

    return resultscell;
```

}

Comment: *pull the items from an array, with no success* - what exactly didn't work again? do you mean you need to cache them but haven't done that yet?

Comment: Please show how you populate your table data in cellForRowAtIndexPath.